# Wiring washer, dryer, tankless water heater

Tags: wiring, circuit-breaker, dryer, washer, tankless

Trying to wire for washer/dryer combo in the garage, and we need to add a tankless water heater to get hot water to the washer. In their current location, there's a (EDIT: 15) AMP circuit for washer, and one for the dryer. Both are electric. The water heater requires up to 33A, and needs a double-pole 40A breaker. It also runs 240V (washer 110, dryer 240). To make this fit in the box, I'm hoping I can make some combo of either the washer or dryer on that double pole as well.

EDIT TO CLARIFY: We have two open spaces to work with in the panel, I'm trying to see how I can combine one of the other appliances with the heater in that open 2-pole spot. (See @Harper below)

Electrical newbie, but am I correct in thinking that the best way would be:
-50A double pole with 6/3 to the heater (max 33A) and washer (Dr. Google says max 10). I already ran 10/3, but it looks like that's nowhere near enough to carry this load. It's exposed 20 feet, so I don't mind re-running.
-Leave the dryer on dedicated 30A circuit.

Does this sound reasonable? Is there a simpler way that I am missing? (or is this DOA and all three need to be on different circuits?)

Thanks!
Jeff

Comment: Your washer is on a 30 A circuit? That's rather atypical - are you sure it's not a regular 15 or 20 A?

Comment: `to make this fit in the box`. You're saying you only have 2 spaces left in your service panel and that will only fit one 2-pole breaker.  Ok. That's solvable, but not that way.

Comment: Is the garage attached or detached?

Comment: @mmathis- you're right. Washer is only on 15. Apologies.

Comment: @Harper-- it's attached. You're right that I currently have two open spaces in the service panel (to fit a 2-pole breaker). I'm trying to combine the circuits to make them work with the two open slots I have to work with.

Comment: @user50459 Do you mean you have exactly two open slots which would allow only one 2-pole breaker? Or do you mean you have slots for two 2-pole breakers, i.e., four single slots?

Comment: @JimStewart - In total, I have three open slots to work with here-- the one 30 A currently routed to the dryer, and two open slots to allow one 2-pole breaker. I'm hoping that I can combine any two of these appliances on to 1 2-pole breaker, to fill the two open slots, and leave the third appliance on the current dryer 30 A breaker.

Comment: The dryer and the tankless water heater each must be on its own dedicated 240 V circuit, 30-A for the dryer 40-A for the water heater. The dryer and the tankless heater cannot be on the same circuit. The washer cannot share one leg of either of these two circuits. Is the dryer currently connected to a 2-pole 30-A breaker? Is the washer on a 15-A or 20-A 120 V breaker? Then there is room for one 2-pole 40-A breaker for the  tankless water heater.

Comment: @user50459 15 and 20 A circuits can supply many fixtures, but anything higher must be on a dedicated circuit. So, your dryer and heater need to be separate. Your panel may accommodate tandem breakers, which put 2 (120 V, generally 15 or 20 A) circuits into 1 space in the panel. If your panel supports these, that could free up space for another 240 V breaker.

Comment: You could install a sub-panel.

Comment: Late advice: buy a washing machine cabable of heating it's own water: you'll avoid the expenses of an additional water heater.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you mean to say is you need a [quadruplex 40/30](https://www.westwayelectricsupply.com/mp230240ct2-breaker-1-40a-2p-1-30a-2p-10k-mh-t.html?gclid=CjwKEAjw85DIBRCy2aT0hPmS1jkSJAC1m9UvT0W7M1ZZNSETH2MmIplK1Uup0poR2hIv-Dk1gR-A0RoCsnXw_wcB).

The tankless would be fed with a #8/2 <strike>#6/2</strike> to suffice the 33 amp requirement. ( black/white/ground ) unless for some reason it requires a neutral then #8/3 <strike>#6/3</strike> ( Black/red/white/ground ).

The existing dryer 30 amp breaker would be replaced with the quadruplex.  The dryer #10 would connect to the 30 amp side, and the #6 would connect to the 40 amp side.

Note: The panel should indicate how many, if any, quadruplex it can allocate.  Also, the breaker obviously needs to match the panels manufacturer.

Comment: There is already a 30-A 2-pole 240 V breaker for the dryer, right? Why not just add a 40-A 2-pole breaker for the tankless water heater? Why use the "quadruplex" 40/30?

Comment: I got my quadruplexs & tandems mixed up.  I thought his panel was full..no?